# powershell -- list of filenames in text file -- need to delete string in the beginning and end

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have a list of filenames generated by `dir -Name -filter *.docx > files.txt`
and result is:

```
   LW_DocId01_4_Long-filename.docx
   LW_DocId02_7_Long-filename.docx
   LW_DocId03_3_Long-filename.docx
   LW_DocId04_2_Long-filename.docx
```

Need a list to show only the DocId# and extension, like

```
   DocId01.docx
   DocId02.docx
   DocId03.docx
   DocId04.docx
```

Ideally, in paragraph form with a comma after each item, like:

```
    DocId01.docx, DocId02.docx, DocId03.docx, DocId04.docx
```

Comment: Ok so what is your question?

Comment: oh, how do I remove the string before and after the underscores?

Comment: thanks @Daniel ... but it only worked on one filename. it only worked on the last filename

Comment: How are you importing the list from the file?  `(Get-Content '.\files.txt') -replace '.*?_(.+?)_.*(\..*$)', '$1$2' -join ', '`

Comment: yes,` (get-content files.txt -raw) -replace '.*?_(.+?)_.*(\..*$)', '$1$2' -join ', ' > list2.txt`

Comment: Remove the `-raw` switch.  With -raw you are importing all the lines as a single string instead of as an array of strings which this needs to work correctly.  You can also just skip the file altogether `(dir -Name -filter *.docx) -replace '.*?_(.+?)_.*(\..*$)', '$1$2' -join ', '`

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, that worked perfectly.  btw, do you know of a good powershell tutorial website? they're really useful. thank you so much.